# html email problem

Tags: html, email, html-parsing, html-email

I am sending emails to my members however the email is coming out wrong in Gmail, have a look below:

Originial

> log into your account now » Someone has just sent you a Smile on
>   Penpal Parade. To read it please log into your account and then click
>   on "messages". Don't forget to like us on Facebook!

Gmail (and probably others)

> log into your account now Â» Someone has just sent you a Smile on
>   Penpal Parade. To read it please log into your account and then click
>   on â€œmessagesâ€ . Donâ€™t forget to like us on Facebook!

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a character set mismatch. The `&Acirc;` shows up when you've got UTF-8 source but some other output, like ISO-8859.

... and don't you mean "is coming out **WRONG** in gmail"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use UTF-8 character encoding always. This looks like the typical "paste from word" miscoding.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to replace special HTML characters.

Common ones are:

&trade; = ™

&amp; = &

&quot; = "

&copy; = ©

&raquo; = »

&laquo; = «

&pound; = £

Larger reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

As said earlier this usually happens when copying and pasting from Word, I usually copy from word to Windows Note Pad and then I do a manual entity replace.

There is also on-line tools you can use:

Google "html encoding tool"